# Python/Pycharm Ctrl+Space Suggestion List Does not show explanations

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

In pycharm ide of python, ctrl+space shortcut is bringing available properties,methods etc.(auto completion also) but the list has no explanations. In other words, I see available options in the list but when i hower the mouse on them there is no explanation is coming so I have no idea what do these options stand for.

Is there any idea to see the explanations ? Or is there any setting that I must configure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> try <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to see definitions, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to see documentations.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have to set the path to python environment, so it knows where your packages are and can look through them to tell you tips. Check this in PyCharm interpreter options